# How to add controls on dialog which has predefind WPF theme?

Tags: wpf, dialog, styles, themes, resourcedictionary

I am new to WPF. I want to do something like this:
I have multiple dialogs in an application. I have created one theme with the required background, title bar and close button I want for all dialogs. Whereas, all dialogs size, and controls for them will differ.
For example: DialogWindow is a theme I have created for Window control.

On MainWindow (where I apply this DialogTheme), I can see this theme.
But when I try to add controls on it, they do not show up on the theme.

```
<Window x:Class="Example.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="391" Width="616"
    Style="{DynamicResource DialogWindow}">
    <Window.Resources>        
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/DialogsTheme.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

I am not sure, what is going wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "when I add controls they do not show up on the theme"? What controls are they? What are you expecting? ... A style or theme as you have mentioned targets a specific control type... in this case a window... other control types will need their own theme.

Comment: As I mentioned, I have created a theme to apply for every dialog. The theme contains only background, customized title bar, and customization of windows- maximize, minimize and close button on the top. Now I want to apply this theme to all dialogs as their base appearance, and want to have every dialog it *own set of controls* for their respective functionality. When I add these controls on that predefined theme, those do not show up on that theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got an answer, ContentPresenter is a thing required, which works as client area for window theme.

```
<ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="ClientArea" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these lines to each window you create to get achieve the style...

```
<Window...Style="{DynamicResource DialogWindow}">
<Window.Resources>        
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/DialogsTheme.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: I am able to access that style in every dialog. Problem is that, when I add any controls on that theme applied background, they do not show up. Only thing it shows is applied theme/style.